# htaccess dynamic URLs redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Hello i want to redirect some dynamic URL to some static urls 
e.g

- /folder/index.php?rid=321

to

- http ://example.com/folder/some-name-321.htm

And

- /folder/index.php?rid=324

to

- http ://example.com/folder/some-other-name-324.htm

I tried

```
Redirect 301 /folder/index.php?rid=321 http ://example.com/folder/some-name-321.htm
Redirect 301 /folder/index.php?rid=324 http ://example.com/folder/some-other-324.htm
```

But not working.
How i should redirect these URLs
Also, where should i place my htaccess file. 
This should be in /folder/.htaccess or i should place rules in main htaccess file present in root of site.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can never match against a Query string using `Redirect` (mod-alias) directive. To manipule query strings you  need to use `mod-rewrite` the following rule in `/root.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^rid=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://example.com/folder/some-name-%1.htm? [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: I tried this, but no avail, after trying this when i visit /folder/index.php?rid=321  it dosen't redirected to http ://example.com/folder/some-name-321.htm

Comment: Well, I used the follow  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)rid=325($|&)
RewriteRule ^folder/index\.php$ /folder/some-name-325.htm [L,R=301]

But it redirecting to http://example.com/folder/some-name-325.htm?rid=325

While i need only http://example.com/folder/some-name-325.htm